# acces denied in windows gitlab runner

Tags: windows, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to execute command cmd /c "D:\Studio\UiRobot.exe execute -f D:\test_robot_pack.1.0.1.nupkg”. Now if I do this locally, I would be able to execute it. However, everytime i run the code in the gitlab pipeline, it always output error: “Access denied”. I hjave already given the full permistion by  cmd /c "icacls D:\Studio\ /q /c /t /grant Users:F" .But still itb has same issue. Please help .

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
```

- build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
stage: build
script:
- cmd /c whoami
- cmd /c net localgroup Users
# - cmd /c more D:\test_robot_pack.1.0.1.nupkg
- cmd /c "icacls D:\Studio\ /q /c /t /grant Users:F"
- cmd /c "D:\Studio\UiRobot.exe execute -f D:\test_robot_pack.1.0.1.nupkg"